# Strapi Webpack stucks in Docker Container

Tags: node.js, docker, webpack, yarnpkg, strapi

I created a project using

```
npx create-strapi-app my-project --quickstart
```

created a Dockerfile:

```
FROM strapi/base

WORKDIR /srv/app

COPY ./package.json ./
COPY ./yarn.lock ./

RUN yarn install

COPY . .

ENV NODE_ENV production

RUN yarn build

EXPOSE 1337

CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

Now i'm trying to build the Docker Image, but it stucks always when building the webpack.

When I manually start yarn build in the container, then i can see that it's stuck at 90% processing chunk assets.

My container has 4GB Ram and 2 cpus attached. I can see that its using 100% SSD Read the whole time.

Do you have any suggestions?

[Strapi Docker Github issue](https://github.com/strapi/strapi-docker/issues/313)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
FROM strapi/base

WORKDIR /srv/app

COPY ./package.json ./
COPY ./yarn.lock ./
COPY . .
RUN yarn install

ENV NODE_ENV production

RUN yarn build

EXPOSE 1337

CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

I think `COPY . .` Before `yarn install` was the issue

Comment: => [7/7] RUN yarn build 3881.2s

Its not completing...